# Snowflake invalid identifier when performin a join

Tags: left-join, outer-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been trying to do an outer join across two different tables in two different schemas. I am trying to filter out before from the table variants the character that are smaller than 4 and bigger than 5 digits. The join was not working with a simply where clause in the end, hence this decision.

The problem is if I do not put the quotes, Snowflake will say that I put invalid identifiers. However, when I run this with the quotes, it works but I get as values in the fields of the column `raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU` only named as the column name, all across the table!

```
SELECT
    analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_description,
    'raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU'
FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants
    WHERE LENGTH('raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU')<=5
      and LENGTH('raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU')>=4
) ON 'analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_id'
      = 'raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU'
```

Is there a way to work this around? I am confused and have not found this issue on forums yet!

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly single quote define a string literal `'this is text'` where as double quotes are table/column names `"this_is_a_table_name"`

add alias's to the tables makes the SQL more readable, and the duplicate length command can be reduced with a between, thus this should work better:

```
SELECT pc.product_description,
    sp.SKU
FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category AS PC
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SKU
    FROM raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants 
    WHERE LENGTH(SKU) BETWEEN 4 AND 5
) AS sp
    ON pc.product_id = sp.SKU;
```

So I reduced the sub-selects results as you only used `sku` from sp but given you are comparing `product_id` to `sku` as your example exists you don't need to join to sp.

the invalid indentifiers implies to me something is named incorrectly, the first step there is to check the tables exist and the columns are named as you expect and the type of the columns are the same for the `JOIN x ON y` clause via:

```
describe table analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category;
describe table raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants;
```

Comment: Somehow that issue got fixed by just adding the aliases. Thank you. The actualy underlying problem is that one of the joining key is an iNT and the other is a varchar, and I would need to figure out how to convert the int in varchar to have the join going through correctly . Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @lcasucci if you know one side is "always" a int/number you can cast it like "101"::number = 101 otherwise try_to_number("101") will safely try and on failure produce null, thus no match.

Comment: I tried applying the to_varchar but it is telling me that 'Single-row subquery returns more than one row snowflake'